# Change Body Background Image on Hover other Element

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change color of sibling elements on hover using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574668/change-color-of-sibling-elements-on-hover-using-css)

Basically i want to change my body background image on hover of #fb or any other div id i create, i couldn't find a solution for this anywhere

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns">
        <h1 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 40px">Club 77</h1>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="sixteen columns">
        <h3><a href="" id="fb">Facebook</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sixteen columns">
        <h3><a href="">Photos</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sixteen columns">
        <h3><a href="">Contact</a></h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I believe you'll want Javascript, CSS gurus may give you some fancy new workaround, but pure CSS follows the family tree *down*, meaning you cant refer to parent styles from the child, instead use a form of Javascript Hover events (or mouseenter, mouseleave)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best is doing via jQuery:

**First.** Preload the background image:

```
$('<img/>').hide().attr('src', 'images/background.jpg').load(function(){
    $('body').append($(this));
});
```

**Second.** Image mouse over:

```
$('#fb').hover(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("images/background.jpg")');
}, function() {
    $('body').css('background', '');
});
```

Here is JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kGgyY/1/

Comment: Detail, you can adjust the style of his background as needed (in this case, if not as my example and you want to stay 100% on screen)

Answer (score 1):

Believe for that you would need to fall-back to relying on a javascript event listener. One that would listen to onmouseover/onmouseout of your `#fb` div and change the class-name of the `<body>` tag as required.
Never seen any other way to change an elements style based on a childs `:hover` status.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this the body element (it will instead have to be a div) has to be nested inside the #fb. On hover call the nested div. Set the nested div to position absolute and height/width 100%. If you need bigger than 100% then can't use AP because it will create scrollbars. In which case you can use position fixed with height/width 999em. That may work. You'll have some z-index issues to work out.