# Move other elements when an element is hovered over

Tags: html, css

I have three items on a menu: Galleries, Contact and About. When the user hovers over galleries I want contact and about to move down and I am having trouble doing this. Anyone know what I should do?

Here is the HTML that I am using:

```
<div class="nav" align="center">  
<a style="opacity: 0;" class="nav_item" id="galleries">GALLERIES</a><br><br><br>
<div id="lower">
<a style="opacity: 0;" class="nav_item" id="about">ABOUT</a><br><br><br>
<a style="opacity: 0;" class="nav_item" id="contact">CONTACT</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#galleries:hover #lower{
top:40%;
-webkit-transition-property:top;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;   
}
```

**EDIT:**

I fixed the problem! Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: The problem with your current CSS is that the #lower element is not a child of the #galleries element.

Comment: Seconding @mavrosxristoforos: Try a :hover on .nav (give it an id if needed)

Comment: Why not set a `margin-bottom` on the `#galleries` (assuming your page flows in a way where this would perform said action...

Comment: I believe he is probably floating these elements next to each other and wants to make it look as if other menu elements are collapsing with your hover.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is impossible to do with just CSS, since you are trying to adjust sibling elements. (You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574668/change-color-of-sibling-elements-on-hover-using-css))

If I needed to do this, I would do it with the Javascript `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events, or with jQuery (which would simplify your code a lot).

Comment: Please update your answer instead of posting it here, for others to see it, too.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, under your current HTML:

```
#nav:hover ~ #lower a {
    top: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wXyRq/).

This uses the general-sibling (`~`) combinator to identify later-siblings (*not* all siblings) of the `#nav:hover` element, and animates them.

I've used `40px` rather than `40%` because a percentage change requires a known-height from the parent, which isn't identified in your question.

Incidentally, all your elements have an `opacity` of `0` (in your posted HTML), with the exception of the `div` and `br` elements, how are your users supposed to identify an interactive component they can't see?