# Can I "transform" a sibling with CSS on hover?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transforms, siblings

I was wondering if I can tranform an object A when I´m hovering a sibling B (only with CSS if possible). This is my code:

```
<div id="block-1">
    <a href="whatever.hml">
        <img class="imgZoom" src="image.jpg" height="300">
        <div style="height: 86px;" class="caption"> &nbsp;</div>
        <div class="caption-text">
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <h4>subheader</h4>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

.imgZoom is just this:

```
.imgZoom {
     -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
     -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease; /* Firefox */
     -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease; /* IE 9 */
     -o-transition: all 0.4s ease; /* Opera */
     transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

I want to hover .caption-text and apply a transform to imgZoom (scale), I guess this is absolutely possible but well, I´m not being able to do it. Can anyone help me or at least tell me if is possible? Thanks.

Comment: its something like `.caption-text:hover + .imgZoom {}`

Comment: CSS selectors cannot traverse the DOM upwards. So if your `img` is below `.caption-text` then there is a chance.

Comment: @mador: No, `+` selects only when the element is the next adjacent sibling.

Comment: @Harry, its not upwards (if i see correctly).. .caption-text and .zoomImg are on the same level.

Comment: @mador: But the `img` is the previous sibling in the DOM (upwards as in, present prior to this element in the DOM) and `+` selects only the next adjacent sibling.

Comment: basically it's not possible with CSS or CSS3. please refer to this thread ->

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574668/change-color-of-sibling-elements-on-hover-using-css

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a previous sibling selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Answer (score 4):

you can do this as was mentioned in comments `.caption-text:hover + .imgZoom {}`
but you have to move img right ater element you want to hover

```
<div id="block-1">
    <a href="whatever.hml">
        <div style="height: 86px;" class="caption"> &nbsp;</div>
        <div class="caption-text">
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <h4>subheader</h4>
        </div>
        <img class="imgZoom" src="image.jpg" height="300">
    </a>
</div>
```

if you need element in order you stated, you need use javascript

Comment: I need them in that order, the caption is over the img... so ok, no CSS then.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @torpedete: You could still try using absolute positioning or negative margins etc :)

Comment: I don't really understand the down-vote on the answer to be honest. It is explicitly mentioned by the author that a markup change is required and there is no other pure CSS way that I could think of.

Comment: No way, I´m finishing this big project and I´m not gonna change the layout now, javascript and no worries :)

Thanks mate.

Comment: @torpedete: That's ok mate. Final decision on whether to use or not is always yours :)