# Change style of an element when focusing a non-related element

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I focus the input text element, I want to change the background color of the submit button.

```
<input id="submit-element" type="submit">
<span><input id="text-element" type="text"></span>
```

However, based on the current setup of the elements, I believe the span blocks them from being sibling elements and being able to use the `~` selector.

So how can I accomplish this? Is JavaScript necessary?

Comment: Use JavaScript! May the Force be with you.

Comment: See related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574668/change-color-of-sibling-elements-on-hover-using-css

Comment: CSS cannot go up the DOM. So either change the order of HTML or use Javascript

Answer (score 2):

With current DOM you're forced to use javascript. Below there is a jQuery solution.

```
$('input#text-element').focus(function() {
    $('input#submit-element').css('color', 'red');
});

$('input#text-element').focusout(function() {
    $('input#submit-element').css('color', 'black');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use JavaScript since the DOM is restricted from CSS. Try the following, which uses the `onblur` and `onfocus` input parameters:

```css
.button { 
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font: 13px sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-color: #aaa #444 #444 #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #000
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button" id="submit-element">New Element</a>
<span><input id="text-element" type="text" onfocus="document.getElementById('submit-element').style.backgroundColor = 'red'" onblur="document.getElementById('submit-element').style.backgroundColor = 'inherit'"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

HTML

```
<input id="submit-element" type="submit">
<input id="text-element" type="text">
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("text-element").addEventListener("focus", changeSubmitF);

function changeSubmitF(){
    document.getElementById("submit-element").style.backgroundColor = "#f4f4f4";
}

document.getElementById("text-element").addEventListener("blur", changeSubmitB);

function changeSubmitB(){
    document.getElementById("submit-element").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eoajuk85/)