# Display a <li> from a different <ul> when I hover on a <li> from another <ul>

Tags: css, hover, html-lists

I'm trying to display a li when an another li from a different ul is hovered , but i didn't have success until now.Can you help me ? Thank you !

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <ul id="child1">
        <li id="child1a">bla bla</li>
        <li id="child1b">bla bla</li>
        <li id="child1c">bla bla</li>
        <li id="child1d">bla bla</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="child2">
        <li id="child2a">bla bla</li>
        <li id="child2b">bla bla</li>
        <li id="child2c">bla bla</li>
        <li id="child2d">bla bla</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#child2a {display:none;}
#child1a:hover #child2a {display:block}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t9y4wu61/

Comment: afaik hover only work with child not sibling

Comment: so possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574668/change-color-of-sibling-elements-on-hover-using-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need more than just CSS to solve this. But first of all, your approach contains a logical mistake:

```
#child1a:hover #child2a {display:block}
```

Adding a space between selectors means that they are nested in the markup. So your CSS would work just fine for something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <ul id="child1">
        <li id="child1a">
            <span id="child2a">bla bla</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But of course, this is not what you want. To get things working, you will need JavaScript. I recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#child1a").mouseover(function() {
        $("#child2a").show();
    };
    $("#child1a").mouseoout(function() {
        $("#child2a").hide();
    };
}
```

Please note that I did not test this code, so it might have some issues. However it might lead you into the right direction. See the linked jQuery website for reference and code examples.

Comment: Actually, I like your solution even more than mine! :) Good job