# CSS (SCSS) Select sibling class on hover element

Tags: html, css, sass, siblings

Is it possible to remove/change styles on sibling class on hover using pure CSS?

I've tried something like this and failed miserably.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
   <li class="item active">name1</li>
   <li class="item">name2</li>
   <li class="item">name3</li>
   <li class="item">name4</li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS**

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  li {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 12px 16px;

    &.active {
       background-color: $primary-blue;
       color: white;
    }

    &:hover {
       background-color: $primary-blue;
       color: white;

       ~ .active {
         background-color: white !important;
         color: black !important;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

So what do i want to achieve... I want to HOVER on any element to give it specific style and at the same time i want to hide style of active element. The active element is random, it can be third, second, first, fourth etc... List goes up to 10 elements. This example is simplified.

**EDIT! IMPORTANT!**
I see people have problems understanding what the hell do i want, i hope this plunker will clarify everything :)

https://plnkr.co/edit/RQy04Qv1zy0nukhnlN82

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: use simple word : you want to hover on which elemnt and you want to change which element ?

Comment: I want to hover any element, and hide styles of active element (active element can be any)

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You need Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Comment: @MirosławKosiorkiewicz That's what Demo 2 does. If you hover over **anything within the list** the items all behave the same even the active item. If you click the left button, then the normal behavior of an active item persists. **Note all demos in my answer are pure CSS**. So to recap...click the left button so that it says:"INACTIVE", then proceed to hover over the list. The desired behavior is: **all items hovered over behave the same, if nothing is hovered over, active item is highlighted again.**

Answer (score 2):

With the given layout, the only *pure CSS* solution is possible with the `order` *property* (using *Flexbox* or *Grid*):

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}
 
li:last-child {
  order: -1; /* moved back up to achieve the same layout */
}
 
.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

li:hover ~ .active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="item">name2</li>
 <li class="item">name3</li>
 <li class="item">name4</li>
 <li class="item active">name1</li> <!-- has to be the last in order for the ~ selector to take effect -->
</ul>
```

Comment: but  i suppose the active class can be on any li element

Comment: Yeah, as Temani said. Active class can be on any li element, so this solution gives me nothing :) However good to know how "~" selector works.

Comment: Yes, usual behavior. Then we have a problem. :) Can't be done without JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

> *"So what do i want to achieve... I want to HOVER on any element to give it specific style and at the same time i want to hide style of active element. The active element is random, it can be third, second, first, fourth etc... List goes up to 10 elements."*

---

It's possible to get that behavior using only CSS, *but the layout needs to change* because using a pure CSS solution for complex behavior involves:

1. Specific element positions in relation to other elements. Parent/Ancestor to Child/Descendant and Sibling relationships must be carefully planned due to CSS cascading and inheritance limitations.
2. Special attributes and default behavior of certain elements that are unique to a group, type, tag, etc. are needed. So just using a list and CSS will not get the behavior you want.

### Layout

1. `<input id='chx0' type="checkbox" hidden='true'>` are invisible switches that determine other elements' *state* (a specific set of styles). One state is active for all affected elements when a checkbox is **[`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)** or not checked.
2. `<label id='btn0' for='chx0'></label>` are buttons that the user clicks and in turn remotely clicks the checkbox that's targeted by this attribute:
   **[`for=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)** `"chx0"`
3. Due to cascading of rulesets only elements that ***proceed*** the checkboxes can be affected which is basically any sibling element that is ***next*** down the DOM tree (including that sibling's children/descendants.) I think of it in human family terms:

   ***Previous-Element-Sibling*** `<section>`**Older Brother**`</section>`

   **Point of Reference** **🢂** `<input id='chx0' type='checkbox'>`

   ***Next-Element-Sibling*** `<li>`**Younger Brother**`</li>`

   You can pick on your younger brother but you can't pick on your older brother.
4. In **Demo 2**, there are 2 checkbox/label combos:

   - <kbd>ACTIVE / INACTIVE</kbd> handles how the `.active` element behaves.
   - <kbd>ORDER / CHAOS</kbd> manipulates the **[`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)** of the `<dd>` (not a requirement just added for fun)

---

I don't know SCSS but from what I can see is that you are expecting a sibling or siblings to change in style, but from what I see, the [**general sibling combinator `~`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) is working but the style is ineffectual: white background and black text. This demo is using the [**adjacent sibling combinator** `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) with the inverse colors so you can actually see a change.

### Demo 1

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

li.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

li:hover+li {
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item active">name1</li>
  <li class="item">name2</li>
  <li class="item">name3</li>
  <li class="item">name4</li>
</ul>
```

### Demo 2

```css
.dataList {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.btn {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: 20px 0 -15px 30px;
  border: 2px ridge grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12ch;
  text-align: center;
}

#btn0::before {
  content: 'ACTIVE';
  color: green;
}

#chx0:checked~#btn0::before {
  content: 'INACTIVE';
  color: tomato;
}

#btn1::before {
  content: 'ORDER';
  color: blue;
}

#chx1:checked~#btn1::before {
  content: 'CHAOS';
  color: orange;
}

#chx1:checked~.dataList dd:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: 8
}

#chx1:checked~.dataList dd:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 5
}

#chx1:checked~.dataList dd:nth-of-type(3) {
  order: 6
}

#chx1:checked~.dataList dd:nth-of-type(4) {
  order: 10
}

#chx1:checked~.dataList dd:nth-of-type(5) {
  order: 3
}

#chx1:checked~.dataList dd:nth-of-type(6) {
  order: 2
}

#chx1:checked~.dataList dd:nth-of-type(7) {
  order: 4
}

#chx1:checked~.dataList dd:nth-of-type(8) {
  order: 1
}

#chx1:checked~.dataList dd:nth-of-type(9) {
  order: 7
}

#chx1:checked~.dataList dd:nth-of-type(10) {
  order: 9
}

.data {
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border: 2px inset white;
  padding: 3px 5px
}

.active {
  color: gold;
  border: 2px ridge gold;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.active::after {
  content: ' is ACTIVE';
  font-weight: 900;
}

#chx0:checked~.dataList:hover .data.active {
  border: 2px inset white;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#chx0:checked~.dataList:hover .active::after {
  content: '';
  font-weight: normal;
}

.data:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.data.active:hover {
  color: lime;
  border-color: lime;
  background: #000;
}

#chx0:checked~.dataList .data.active:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input id='chx0' type='checkbox' hidden='true'>
<input id='chx1' type='checkbox' hidden='true'>

<label id='btn0' class='btn' for='chx0'></label>
<label id='btn1' class='btn' for='chx1'></label>

<dl class='dataList'>
  <dt class='data term'>DATA LIST</dt>
  <dd class='data'>ITEM 0</dd>
  <dd class='data'>ITEM 1</dd>
  <dd class='data'>ITEM 2</dd>
  <dd class='data'>ITEM 3</dd>
  <dd class='data active'>ITEM 4</dd>
  <dd class='data'>ITEM 5</dd>
  <dd class='data'>ITEM 6</dd>
  <dd class='data'>ITEM 7</dd>
  <dd class='data'>ITEM 8</dd>
  <dd class='data'>ITEM 9</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add the ampersand to the active selector as well, like so:

```
li {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 12px 16px;

    &.active {
       background-color: $primary-blue;
       color: white;
    }

    &:hover {
       background-color: $primary-blue;
       color: white;

       ~ &.active {
         background-color: white !important;
         color: black !important;
       }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but no. I've tried a lot of variations :/ I wonder if its possible at all.

Comment: A no, it's not... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574668/change-color-of-sibling-elements-on-hover-using-css