# How to hover different size pictures

Tags: css, web, hover

I am trying to do the hover effect with different size images. I would like to know if there is a way to always hide on of the pictures while the other one is being hovered?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. can you [create minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yup you can do it with JS and CSS. make a condition when the cursor is on a particular image the other image will hide.

Comment: I think you can do it only with CSS. You can assign a different class to each image and then use ':hover' to affect others images.

Comment: If you are looking to affect other images in the same container as the one that is hovered, look for sibling element hover solutions. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574716/762640