# How can I change the color of the places I want when the li element hover?

Tags: html, css

I have css and html codes as below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}

nav ul li:hover .top-content {
  background: red;
}

nav ul li:hover main {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-content"></div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main></main>
</div>
```

What I want is for the .top-content class and main element to be colored red when I hover over the li elements. But as far as I understand, I'm having a problem with the selectors. How can I change the color of these elements using css only?

Comment: Can you change your html structure ? if not you cannot do it in Css only

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

*CSS properties cannot modify anything but elements and their children (they cannot access parents or siblings).*  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574716/9256189).

You need to take aid of JavaScript, to achieve this.

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li");
let topContent = document.querySelector(".top-content"); 

let main = document.querySelector("main"); 

lis.forEach(li=>{
  li.onmouseover = ()=>{
    topContent.style.background = "red";
    main.style.background = "red";
  }
  li.onmouseleave = ()=>{
    topContent.style.background = "gray";
    main.style.background = "green";
  }
  
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-content"></div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main></main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, what I wanted to do was to add an overlay to these fields while the li element is in the hover state. I guess i cant, thank you again.

Comment: Welcome. What kind of overlay you want to add? Just asking.